# Does a low-pass filter average the higher-order frequencies into a "DC offset"?

Tags: pid-controller, low-pass, mixer, cutoff-frequency

In a Pound-Drever-Hall lock, an electronic signal is produced of the form:

[image]

We are interested in electronically isolating the term:
[image]

My question is: **how can we filter to get exactly this term (listed above) without any time-dependent terms**?

I know that I can use a bandpass filter around the frequency $\Omega$ will isolate this term:

[image]

We don't want the time-dependent terms in the signal and instead we want the imaginary term without frequency:

[image]

In the literature, it says that we can combine this signal (using a mixer) with a frequency \$cos(\Omega t)\$ - and a low-pass filter.. but how exactly does this work?

Mixing the signals will produce a term \$cos(\Omega)^2\$. I understand that the average of the signal will have a DC-offset. But if my electronics has a high bandwidth, then this isn't really helping eliminate the time-dependence in these terms, right?

So, in summary, can I use a mixer and a low-pass filter to extract out that particular term? And, if so, how exactly does it work?

**Additional information:**

(This isn't that important for answering the question, but if you are interested) the function F(omega) is:
[image]
And we are interested in isolating this particular term because it produces a good looking "error signal" that looks like this picture:
[image]

Comment: I only skimmed what you wrote in about 10 seconds, or so. But one thing to look for is a way to convert sine and cosine terms into sine-squared plus cosine-squared terms (because the sum of the two is 1 and eliminates time, if you can achieve it.) Complex conjugate is a way (squaring magnitude.) But I'd need to spend more time than I have right now to read through the details. Just wanted to toss that out to see if it sticks for you. You've spent more time on this, so my apologies for spending so little of my own so far. I may return later.

Comment: for those interested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Drever%E2%80%93Hall_technique

Comment: Is \$\Omega\$ a fixed value you know in advance, or something that can vary?

Comment: @The Photon:  This is basically my doubt (answered by OP  below) posed in a different manner.

Comment: @DirceuRodriguesJr, No, I really mean is it a fixed value, not just one that's available in some signal in the system. Because it looks to me like you could extract the desired signal by just bandpass filtering around frequency \$\Omega\$ and then using a peak detector or power detector, with no need for the downmixing proposed in Edgar's answer.

Comment: Now looking at the Wiki page on PDH locking, I suspect you specifically want the \$\Im[\cdot\]\$ term and not the \$\Re[\cdot]\$ part, so this isn't viable. But also, OP, it means you mis-state the situation when you say that bandpass filtering will isolate the term you want.

Comment: @ThePhoton, Yes you are right, I am only concerned with the Imaginary part of that quantity. You are also right in pointing out that I should not mention a Band pass filter. I will correct that. To answer your question about Ω, I can vary it by around 20% because it also changes other things in my experiment. Thank you!

Comment: @ThePhoton In the question, I was trying to explain my thought process as to why just a bandpass filter would not be enough to obtain the term I am interested in. In the later part of the question, I mention that many resources say that a mixer followed by a low-pass filter is required. From the comments it seems as though the purpose of the low-pass filter is to perform an integration over time to extract out this term after the mixer (which I have heard as a process called "demodulation"). I was not aware of a low-pass filter as an "integrator."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the specific question in your title: no, a low pass filter does not “average higher order frequencies” it attenuates them.

To answer your actual question: yes, the basic procedure of demodulation and filtering will do what you want.

The math is rather straightforward. Simply multiply by \$ \sin(\Omega t) \$ and integrate over one period and you will see the term you want. Given your equation, using \$ \sin(\Omega t) + \cos(\Omega t)\$  instead as the multiplier should produce a cleaner result.

The issue is in how to implement the integration in a way that does not compromise your feedback loop stability. The simplest way is to use a low pass filter with a cutoff frequency of at most \$ \Omega  / 2\$ to ensure the removal of feedthrough and double-frequency components.

Do note that a real-life continuous integrator is always just a low-pass filter. An actual integrator has infinite gain at DC, real components with real finite gains and leakage will limit this gain to perhaps \$ 10^5 \$ if not less, which directly implies a low-pass response.

Of course, much lower cutoff frequencies are commonly used, so as to have low-order practical filters. How much attenuation is necessary will depend on your application, but in general you would use filter that has a bandwidth not much higher than that of your signal of interest (in this case your feedback loop response speed).

You can also design a filter with specific zeros at the problematic frequency components (\$ \Omega \& 2\Omega \$). But in most cases, a very simple low pass is much more than enough.

Comment: Could you go more into detail about this 'low-pass = integration' part? 

First you say: "a low pass filter does not “average higher order frequencies” it attenuates them."  - but then you say that a low pass filter can obtain the term of interest through "integration."  You say low-pass filter can implement this "integration", but it doesn't have to do with some of the frequency modes reducing to their time averages?

Comment: First note that formally you require integration over one (or more) full periods, this is not what you get unless you explicitly implement it. Second, a continuous integrator is just a first-order low-pass whose cutoff frequency has been set to zero. Third, the “average” of any frequency component (except DC) is zero not a “DC offset”. Fourth, mere examination of the modulated equation shows that ideally all you need is the removal of the double-frequency component, an ideal low-pass filter does that, a real filter just attenuates it.

Comment: @Edgar Brown: I do not know the details of this laser-focused experience in this way. So, just one question: Is the signal \$sin (\Omega t)\$ continuously available in the experiment (in order to be multiplied with \$P_{inc}\$) or would it need to be generated and synchronized?

Comment: @DirceuRodriguesJr you are asking the wrong person. Given the way the question was formulated I simply assumed it was available. If not, it’s possible to derive it from the signal itself with some compromises.

Comment: @EdgarBrown, Thank you for your answer. I understand parts of it. I am not an expert in electronics, to say the least, so please bear with me. I looked up 'why, when and how a low pass filter(LPF) acts an integrator. I found that in the limit of your input frequency being much much greater than your cutoff frequency, your low pass filter is going to act as an integrator. Also, the LPF not only integrates but as a result of its integration, ends up attenuating the signal too. That means I need to balance integration and attenuation because I want the former and limit the latter. Continued..

Comment: So my question comes down to : If my modulation frequency is 10MHz, I want a LPF for which the cutoff frequency is much much smaller than 10MHz, right? So what does 'much much smaller' mean? 5 times smaller? 10  times smaller?

Comment: @DirceuRodriguesJr Yes I have the signal continuously available because I also use it for another purpose during the experiment. So what I do is, I have light coming from a laser, I modulate it(because that helps in manufacturing a good looking error signal that helps me lock my system using a PDH lock.) I make this modulated light get reflected from an optical cavity, measure the intensity of the reflected signal, demodulate it using a mixer. So my modulation and demodulation signals are the same and are readily available. Sorry if I inundated you with unnecessary details.

Comment: @SonaliGera That depends on one of two things, either of which is constrained by your design criteria. (1) The order/shape of the filter and the desired level of attenuation, or more likely (2) the bandwidth of your feedback loop. If you use a simple 1st order filter 1/10 of your frequency will be 20dB of attenuation (26dB at the problematic double frequency component), for some applications this would be enough. A different filter would perform differently. But if all you need is 5kHz for your control loop, then a filter at 10kHz will have a reduced influence and provide 60dB of attenuation.

Comment: @SonaliGera just to be clear, I used “integrator” just because the math is straightforward for anyone with no frequency-domain intuition but grasps the idea of an average. But by mere inspection of the modulation product it should be obvious that all that is needed is to attenuate/eliminate the higher frequency components while isolating “DC”. However your actual desired signal is not DC, it has a wide spectrum that represents your feedback error, an actual integrator would also filter that desired signal.

Comment: @EdgarBrown, Yes. I understand that.  I could not find an appropriate LPF in my lab, so we decided to make one on our own with a resistor and capacitor of appropriate values. Thank you!